# How can I edit/tweak Tomato firmware?

Tags: router, firmware, tomato

How do other people tweak or edit Tomato firmware? I'm interested in this because I do not need QoS. I have another router that does not have as much RAM and I want to have a micro Tomato firmware. I know there is DD-WRT micro but I like Tomato much more. What programming language is used in making Tomato firmware?

Answer (score 1):

The latest source for [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) firmware is always [available](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tomatofirmware/files/): why don't you check by yourself?